# Java ResultSet get Returned Field Names

Tags: java, sql, resultset

For standard queries I have not had a problem with this. I simply:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM table_name");
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
    String fieldName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
    System.out.print(fieldName + ",  ");
}
```

But the moment I assign a field name to another name, i.e.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a AS foo, b AS bar FROM table_name");
```

It throws an error because fields `a` and `b` aren't found.

How should I cater to this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between *column name* and *column label*. The methods in `ResultSet` expect column labels. So you should use the method `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel` instead of `ResultSetmetaData.getColumnName`.